# Untestable sections of iOS app and App Store Submission

Tags: ios, geolocation, submission, app-store

I'm currently in the process of specing an application that has a strong geolocation element. I'm worried that some parts of the app will be untestable by Apple because they are only functional in specific locations, meaning an Apple tester will not be able to access them unless they hop on a plane to London which I'm guessing they won't. Has anyone had any experience with such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to submit it immediately, iOS 5 simulator will be able to simulate this behavior like Android simulator.